# SSH connection closed after first password attempt

Tags: ssh, ldap, redhat

So, I'm having a rather weird problem. I have a server, that when I try to SSH into, immediately closes the connection if I type in the correct password on the first attempt. However, if I purposefully enter a wrong password on the first attempt, and then enter a correct password at the second or third prompt, it successfully logs me into the computer. Similarly, when I try to use public key authentication, I get an immediate closed connection. If, however, I enter a wrong password for my key file, followed by another wrong password once it reverts to password authentication, I can successfully log in as long as I provide the correct password at the second or third prompt.

The machine is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago), and is using LDAP for authentication. Any ideas on where to start debugging this one?

Comment: Did you figure it out ? I have same problem